# Instruction for training model in Stanford Core NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis, training-data

I am a novice in the area of sentiment analysis, and I am very interested to learn about training models, could you please explain each of the instructions contained in the following command?

java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath train.txt -devPath dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz

what is the function of:
-numHid 25 
-trainPath train.txt 
-devPath dev.txt 
-train 
-model model.ser.gz

Please could you help me?

Comment: I think it'd help if you showed what you had already found out, using google and the docs, and what more specifically you don't understand. E.g. There is a bit of explanation here: https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2013-November/004308.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more complicated options are described in comments in these classes: [`RNNOptions`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/sentiment/RNNOptions.java), [`RNNTrainOptions`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/sentiment/RNNTrainOptions.java).

The remainder of the options you listed are paths for reading / writing during training.

- The `-trainPath` argument points to a labeled sentiment treebank. The trees in this data will be used to train the model parameters (also to seed the model vocabulary).
- The `-devPath` argument points to a second labeled sentiment treebank. The trees in this data will be used to periodically evaluate the performance of the model. We won't train on this data; it will only be used to test how well the model generalizes to unseen data.
- The `-model` argument specifies where to save the learned sentiment model.

Comment: thanks! I have only one question, I want to use a dataset of music, to train (eg train.txt) which I am labeling manually. My question is: is also necessary to manually tag the file: dev.txt?

I do not understand the purpose of dev.txt

Comment: Yes, dev.txt also needs to be labeled in the same way. We need to have some way to estimate the performance of the model on new / unseen data. This is what the dev set is for — you don't show it to your model to your training, and use it to test how the model will perform on "new" examples.